# ColdFusion calling session function

Tags: session, coldfusion, cfc

I have a user object that I would like to have in the session variable and be able to update as needed. How do I call a function in an existing user object that will manipulate the existing variable. I found way to call the function, but it's not calling the existing object, instead I suspect it's instantiating a new object before calling the function.

In Application.cfc:

```
<cffunction name = "onSessionStart" output="no">
    <cfobject name="session._user" component="user"/>
    <cfscript>
    ...
    session._user.init();
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

In User.cfc:

```
<cffunction name = "init">
    <cfscript>
        variables.attributes.variable1 = 0;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="changeVariable" access="public">
    <cfargument name = "somename">
    variables.attributes.variable1 = arguments.somename;
</cffunction>
```

Later on in login.cfm, call `session._user.changeVariable(2)`

If this isn't possible, I'll end up writing to and from database to keep track of user properties instead of using session variable.

Comment: Is what you have above the actual changeVariable function that you are using?  To me, it looks like it has multiple issues, and I wouldn't expect it to work in its current state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In onSessionStart create the object and set it into the session. If you are using CF10+ you can use `new()` in CF9 and lower you need to use `createObject()`.

```
<cffunction name="onSessionStart">
  <!--- in CF10+ new calls init() automatically --->
  <cfset session._user = new user()> 
  <!--- CF9 or lower --->
  <cfset session._user = createObject('user').init()>
</cffunction>
```

In login.cfm simply say this to update the session variable

```
<cfset session._user.changeVariable(2)>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the "cfset" in calling it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never quite done it that way so I'm not sure how that works, but normally I would create the user.cfc file and store the instance in the session.

```
<cffunction name="onSessionStart" output="false">
    <cfset session._user = new user()>
</cffunction>
```

I would also consider possibly using a framework and/or ORM to handle this stuff for you.